Missing AndroidManifest.xml
So I wanted to replace one file in an application, and the way I did it is apktool d CATGAME.apk, which decompiles the .apk.
Then I replaced the one file I need, and do apktool b CATGAME to compile it. Then I zip align the file by running mv CATGAME.apk CATGAME-prealigned.apk; zipalign -v 4 CATGAME-prealigned.apk CATGAME.apk
After which, I do apksigner sign --ks ../ks.jks --v2-signing-enabled true  --v3-signing-enabled true  --min-sdk-version 29 CATGAME.apk(ks.jks in the parent directory is they keystore)
And to verify I run apksigner verify CATGAME.apk but the output is Exception in thread "main" com.android.apksig.apk.ApkFormatException: Missing AndroidManifest.xml at com.android.apksig.ApkSigner.getAndroidManifestFromApk(ApkSigner.java:970) at com.android.apksig.ApkVerifier.getAndroidManifestFromApk(ApkVerifier.java:1225) at com.android.apksig.ApkVerifier.verifyAndGetMinSdkVersion(ApkVerifier.java:640) at com.android.apksig.ApkVerifier.verify(ApkVerifier.java:196) at com.android.apksig.ApkVerifier.verify(ApkVerifier.java:164) at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.verify(ApkSignerTool.java:587) at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.main(ApkSignerTool.java:95) 
After extracting CATGAME.apk I see that now it became two folders META-INF and CATGAME
META-INF contains ALIAS_NA.RSA, ALIAS_NA.SF  and MANIFEST.MF, while CATGAME contains normal things that would be in a normal apk.
I'm trying to make a tool to automate the process of replacing that file so a GUI tool probably won't work.
UPDATE:
You just have to add --append-signature, it took me too long to find out

What happens if you apply apksigner verify on the original APK file? I would also recommend checking the original and the rebuilt APK files with a ZIP tool if they contain AndroidManifest.xml.

What file you replaced , a smali file or resource/xml ?

Also, please attach the sample apk with your post if possible

The solution was easy as adding --append-signature
Sorry for wasting your time, I don't know how I didn't think of that


After extracting CATGAME.apk I see that now it became two folders
META-INF and CATGAME

Sounds like apk is corrupted. AndroidManifest.xml, res/ & smali directories are suppose to be in root of the apk, along with that META-INF folder you mentioned. I guess the commands you used were incorrect (probably zipalign one is wrong)
For reference, try using these commands. They work in my case.
zipalign -p -f -v 4 CATGAME-prealigned.apk CATGAME-zipaligned.apk

apksigner sign --ks Your.keystore --in CATGAME-zipaligned.apk --out CATGAME.apk --v4-signing-enabled true

The alternative version incase keystore is password protected
apksigner sign --in CATGAME-zipaligned.apk --out CATGAME.apk --v4-signing-enabled true --ks YourKey.jks --ks-key-alias yourKeyAlias --ks-pass pass:yourPassword


Reference:
https://developer.android.com/tools/apksigner
https://developer.android.com/tools/zipalign

Or try using uber-apk-signer: https://github.com/patrickfav/uber-apk-signer
